# How to wait for callback event return value

Tags: c#

```
EIDReader eidObj;
static FancyPopup  fancyObj;

    Calss UIpdate
    {
       UIUpdate()
       {
          eidObj = new EIDReader();//only contact card                
          eidObj.DeviceArrival += eidObj_DeviceArrival;  
          eidObj.DataReceived += EIDReader_DataReceived;       
       }
    }

bool eidObj_DeviceArrival(stirng name)
{       
     //device arrived ,                         
      notifyIcon = new TaskbarIcon(this);
      notifyIcon.Icon = Resources.Led;
      notifyIcon.ToolTipText = DeviceName + " Reader Application";
      notifyIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;    
      fancyObj = new FancyPopup();    
      notifyIcon.TrayPopup = fancyObj;
}

bool EIDReader_DataReceived(string[] CardData, string[] PublicData, System.Drawing.Image ImgPhoto)
{
   if (CardData != null)
   {
      fancyObj.ClickCount = PublicData[(int)EIDReader.eCardInfo.CSNValue];
      // Here fancyObj is NULL, so rising exception. And I don't know why it becomes NULL.
   }
  return true;
}

// in another class 
Class EIDReader{
    public delegate bool OnDeviceArrival(string DeviceName);
    public event OnDeviceArrival DeviceArrival;
    
   EIDReader()
   {
    if (DeviceArrival != null)
     {
       DeviceArrival(readerMgr.Readers[mDevType].ReaderName)
    // Here i need to wait for the callback return value since UI update are going in main form.
     }
   }    
}
```

I have many callback events to the UI form and I need to wait for every event whether the UI update is done or not.

e.g. In devicearrival callback event I am updating device name in UI, but I don't know whether UI update is done or not from here.

When calling datareceived() call back event  then fancyobj instance is NULL. Why the fancyobj getting NULL even though I intialize in another callback event.

Comment: What does you handler look like? Unless it's asynchronous, you are waiting for it already.

Comment: The way you have invoked the event you are already waiting here; unless you have started a different thread in your event handler.

Comment: I have edited my question .. pls have look .

Comment: Also Why the  fancyObj instance is NULL. when accessing inside the callback event.  pls help

Comment: I'd say because the DeviceArrival event happens after the DataReceived one, but we're lacking code here.

Comment: @Kilazur, No . first time itself i am raising devicearrival  after  that only i am calling Datareceived() callback.

Comment: It looks fishy to me that fancyObj is static.

Comment: @Philippe,  So  doesnt this give any impact in code ,?

Comment: Not for the null issue you're talking about, but in a multithreaded evnironment you'll probably get race conditions which are pretty hard to reproduce and understand.

Comment: In simple words,  why the class instances are NuLL when accessing the same inside the callback event handler which is calling from separate thread in the another class.